# Custom 'success' message after submitting comment on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to display a success message on successfully posted comment on Wordpress. How to do this?

Comment: Try to extend your question. In what context are you trying to achieve such a thing? You would need to display it without any page reload? So per Ajax? How do you submit the comment? Could you provide a link or a snippet?

Answer (score 3):

Without Ajax or plugins. Add to function.php:

```
add_action( 'set_comment_cookies', function( $comment, $user ) {
    setcookie( 'ta_comment_wait_approval', '1', 0, '/' );
}, 10, 2 );

add_action( 'init', function() {
    if( isset( $_COOKIE['ta_comment_wait_approval'] ) && $_COOKIE['ta_comment_wait_approval'] === '1' ) {
        setcookie( 'ta_comment_wait_approval', '0', 0, '/' );
        add_action( 'comment_form_before', function() {
            echo "<p id='wait_approval' style='padding-top: 40px;'><strong>Your comment has been sent successfully.</strong></p>";
        });
    }
});

add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', function( $location, $comment ) {
    $location = get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '#wait_approval';
    return $location;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: It works on localhost but not on server: Undefined index: ta_comment_wait_approval - Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (...) wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1216

Comment: I made some changes to the code. But I think error "headers already sent" is bug of your theme. On clear "twentytwelve" theme this code works...

Comment: I get the error `Notice: Trying to get property 'comment_status' of non-object in /Users/senya/Developer/Wordpress/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 1200` on the wordpress login screen when using your functions in the `functions.php` file

Answer (score 2):

please try https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ajaxify-comments. it will display a success message on successfully posted comment on Wordpress